# How to return a space from function in vim?

Tags: vim, viml

example:

```
function! MkStatusLine()
  let &stl=''
  let &stl.='%{abcd()}'
endfunction

function abcd()
 if this 
    return ' myvalue'
 elseif this
    return ' '
 endif
endfunction
```

How can I return a space?
return ' '  is seen as return ''
return ' myvalue' is seen as return 'myvalue'

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are misinterpreting your results and that your function is working correctly. Check what

```
:echo '#'.abcd().'#'
```

produces. You should observe `# #` and not `##`.

If not, are you sure there is only two paths in your function?

What about the `else` path? You can debug it with: `:debug echo abcd()`. From there you can go to `n`ext instruction, or `s`tep-in a function call, or `f`inish the call to the current function, you can `c`ontinue till next breakpoint, etc. See `:h :debug`.

What is sure is that spaces can be returned in VimL. If the first line of your function is a `return ' '`, you'll see that a space is returned.

Comment: Hi Luc, tnx for replying. You're right. It works fine but it doesn't work in statusline. I updated my question.

Comment: OK. You only want a single space in that case? May I ask why a space instead of nothing? If it was about padding, there are other ways.

Comment: yes it was about padding. In my example in above question I only have one function in the statusline. In reality I have more functions. If there is a value to return, I want to create a padding of 1 space before the value to return. If not no padding.